# Can I use KVM VM for c++ build agents using ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, kvm

I am using KVM hypervisor and have spun up 2 VMs(16vCpus, 16GB Memory) to run c++ builds. I started off with qcow2 and was seeing performance issues and changed it to raw format, cache=None. The c++ compile does well with raw format, however when the linker is run, the VM crawls and takes a long time to link as memory is swapping. My KVM host is a centos7 machine with 32CPUs, 64GB RAM, SATA drive. Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: If you're swapping, add more RAM.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I had VMWare VM with the same amount of RAM and Swap, however they do not crawl. That VM is using Vmdk.